# How can I get this base = { base: 'base', prop: '2093482938' } array in JavaScript to C#?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, web-applications

`base = { base: 'base', prop: '897070980989'}; ingr_mapArray.push(base); protien = { protein: 'protein', prop: '452341342453'}; ingr_mapArray.puh(protein);`

I want to get **ingr_mapArray** in **C#**. And wants to store in a **List<'Ingrediants>**. How can I get this array?

Comment: For `List<'Ingrediants>` you need the class `Ingrediants`. Both the base and protien objects have different fields. To make it a class they need same fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you should go about it

```
class Ingrediants
{
    string Type { get; set; }
    string Prop { get; set; }
}
```

Then where you need the list you do

```
List<Ingrediants> ingr_mapArray = new List<Ingrediants>();

Ingrediants base = new Ingrediants
{
   Type = "base",
   Prop = "897070980989"
};

ingr_mapArray.Add(base);

Ingrediants protien = new Ingrediants
{
   Type = "protien",
   Prop = "452341342453"
};

ingr_mapArray.Add(protien);
```

In your example, the `base` object has a property `"base"`, and similarly `protien` has `"protien"` which is not something you can do in the same class. So I named it `Type` where you can provide either `base` or `protien`.